# RadGrid - Formatting all items in an entire row based on first column value

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am trying to figure out how I can format the numbers in an entire row based on the first column's value.

For example in the ItemDataBound event I am trying to do the following:

```
if (item["Category"] == "Category 1")
{
     // this makes all items in the row red
     item.ForeColor = Color.Red;

     // now is it possible to format all numbers in the row as percent
}
```

Usually you handle this kind of thing by setting the Format on each column, but in my case my columns are dynamically created and I need to base the format of each row on the first column value.

Some rows need to be formatted as percent, some currency, some decimal.

Here is how the columns of the grid are created if it helps:

```
var boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
gridDealAssumption.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
boundColumn.DataField = "Category";
boundColumn.ItemStyle.Font.Bold = true;


foreach (string product in products)
{
    GridNumericColumn numericColumn = new GridNumericColumn();
    gridDealAssumption.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(numericColumn);
    numericColumn.DataField = product
    numericColumn.HeaderText = product;
}
```

As you can see my Category Column is the only static column and it is a regular bound column. The other columns are all dynamic GridNumericColumns.

Comment: You want to change the color for the entire table row or for specific fields?

Comment: No, I was showing that changing the color is working. I can make the entire row where my Category column = "Category 1". This isn't what I really need to do. I need to actually format the appearance of the rest of the row (which is all numbers) to show as percent, (my second commented line)

Comment: In ItemDataBound you should be able to do anything. Can you provide some example of data that you're expecting to display? It's just hard to give an answer with such limited information.